# Arbitrary intersection of uncountable subfields of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: ring-theory

What is about arbitrary intersection of uncountable nested subfields of $\mathbb{C}$?
Does it have to be uncountable too or it can be countable?

Edit: {\it Nested} subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ means that we are considering an infinite chain of field $F_1, F_2, \dots, F_\alpha,etc..$ of subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ such that for every two ordinals $\beta,\lambda < \kappa$ such that $\beta < \lambda$ we have $F_\beta \supset F_\lambda$ and $\kappa$ is some limit ordinal, which might be uncountable.
Of course we are assuming that every $F_\alpha$ is uncountable for $\alpha < \kappa$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb C$ have uncountably-many subfields?

Comment: Yes, why not? Are you just asking?

Comment: Yes, I don't know that much about the topic. Is this a standard result in the area? Just curious.

Comment: I am not very sure why it is tagged as general topology :O

Comment: I just did not find an appropriate tag.

Comment: What do you mean by uncountable *nested* subfields? I can understand finitely many or countably many nested subfields; how do you define it for uncountably many?

Comment: @BFD: Certainly, $\mathbb C$ has uncountably many subfields. It is rather easy to see; just look at its trascendence degree.

Comment: With the clarification you have made, I think the intersection can be uncountable. The basic idea is that $\mathbb C$ has uncountable transcendence degree over $\mathbb Q$. I am unable to write a proper proof however; it is best done by someone who has a better understanding of set theory.

Comment: Yes but do you thing it {\it must} be uncountable or just it {\it can} be uncountable?

Comment: I am saying that it *can* be uncountable. Sorry, I misread your question to be asking about that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

Let $A=\{a_\alpha\mid\alpha<\kappa\}$ be a set of generators for $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb Q$ (that is, $\Bbb Q(A)=\Bbb C$). Now let $F_\alpha=\Bbb Q(\{a_\beta\mid\alpha<\beta\})$.

Each $F_\alpha$ is uncountable, but $\bigcap F_\alpha=\Bbb Q$.